# I accidentally did ulimit -r1 and I want to go back to ulimit -r90+, how do I do this?

Tags: linux, bash, ulimit

I then get that the hard limit has become 1..is there an easy way to "reset what i did"? This is a server I have logged onto via ssh.

Comment: Did you try to `ssh` twice (in another terminal) to that server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Log out and log back in again.